# Debugging React Native Android source code

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to debug React Native's Android source code. But no matter what changes I make to the source code, it doesn't show up in logcat when running the app. Does anyone know if I have to rebuild the library itself every time I want to see a change?

On iOS any source code changes are instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug react native **andriod's** source code you need to make a new build everytime you change native code.

In case you make changes in react native javascript code you don't need to rebuild, just do a **reload** (open our app in emulator - press RR)

I hope this helps. If not please let me know more about your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know if there is a way to make `react-native run-android` to always rebuild?